# Change system date

Tags: python, date

I need to change my computer's local date to an earlier date (e.g. 2010). I couldnt do that in BIOS. Does anybody know how to do this task, for example by writing a Python snippet?

Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you do it in your BIOS? Why can't you just go to your system settings and reset the date there?

Comment: What platform? If you just need to trick one program, could you put together a quick little library to replace `gettimeofday(2)` and `time(2)` (or whatever the library calls are on your platform)?

Comment: Why are you trying to change the date using Python when your operating system provides the means to do this? That is, what actual problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Windows, you should be able to do that in the time and date control panel (should be self explaining).

If you use Linux, use the date command, and maybe hwclock (more info in the man pages).

If you use AmigaOS, use the appropriate settings window in the system Preferences folder.

If you use any other OS, you should have mentioned here which one you use...

Comment: I use Windows. I can now do it via dos with the command "date 01-01-2010". But it is temporary. I cant change date from control panel or bios. They dont allow me to.

Comment: Hi, Shansal. This sounds as your computer is part of a domain, and your account does not have the necessary privileges. You should ask your sysadmin to add those privileges to your account.

Comment: You are right MarkusSchaber. When I get offline, it is permanent. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not permitted to do this via the operating system, then you will not be permitted to do it from a scripting language like Python, either.